# Double quotes disappeared when passing instructions to the integrated terminal in VS Code

Tags: powershell, batch-file, visual-studio-code

I'm configuring the environment in Visual Studio Code and encountered a problem.

I added a task with the label run in task.json:

```
{
    "label": "run",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "start",
    "args": [
        "cmd",
        "/c\"echo hello && pause\""
    ],
    "problemMatcher": []
}
```

There is the output in terminal when I run it:

> > Executing task in folder cpp: start cmd /c"echo hello && pause" <

And then, it reported an error:

```
In line:1 character: 24
+ start cmd /cecho hello && pause
+                        ~~
mark"&&"is not a valid statement separator in this release.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine
```

The command

```
start cmd /c"echo hello && pause"
```

became

```
start cmd /cecho hello && pause
```

the double quotes disappeared, so it reported the error!

And I can manually run the same command with double quotes correctly.

How could I pass double quotes to the integrated terminal?

I use Powershell as integrated terminal in Windows 10 x64.

Visual Studio Code version: 1.28.2

Comment: What happens if you separate the `/C` option from the doublequoted string; `"cmd", "/c", "\"echo hello & pause\""`

Comment: The double quotes disappeared again and report a error :(

Comment: Try single quotes.

    start cmd /c'echo hello && pause'

Comment: Makes no sense to have start before cmd.exe. start is an internal command to the cmd.exe shell.